# Bounding definite integral above

Tags: analysis, inequality, definite-integrals

Struggling to prove this inequality:
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-R \sin \varphi} \thinspace d\varphi < \frac{\pi}{2R}(1 - e^{-R})
$$
where $R > 0$

I've tried to integrate by parts and get an inequality with the given integral on both sides and also tried to bound integrand itself. Currently, I'm completely out of ideas.

Comment: $\sin\phi\geqslant\frac{2}{\pi}\phi\,\,\text{for}\,x\in[0;\frac{\pi}{2}]\,\Rightarrow\,e^{-R\sin\phi}\leqslant e^{-\frac{2}{\pi}R\phi}$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you, solves everything! Surely I did overcomplicate matters.

Comment: This is one step in proving Jordan's lemma :)